# Electron - maximize button

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm making an electron app and have removed the title bar to make my own, using HTML and ipc-sends to the main.js

I have successfully been able to maximize, minimize and close the app, but I wonder - once maximized, what is the electron-function that calls the "back to window" event that a normal maximize button switches to once the window is full screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is [BrowserWindow.unmaximize](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winunmaximize).

There's also an [unmaximize](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-unmaximize) event, and you can use [isMaximized](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winismaximized) to check whether the window is currently maximized.